# How to View Google Cloud Compute Engine Managed Instance Group, is it a stateful or stateless?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

At first when creating a compute engine managed instance group, the form allow to select the instance group type Managed or unmanaged.

Under managed compute engine instance group, we have option to select stateful or stateless, but after creating the instance group. I do not see the group information **stateful** or **stateless**.

Tried with command, no luck:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups list | describe
```

Please suggest, thanks.

---

Answer (score 1):

In console, in [Instance groups](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups/list), **Group type** will be set as "Stateful" or "Managed".
Using commands, however, is a bit tricky. The best I could find is to list instances in group and check disk autodelete setting:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances GROUP_NAME
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME| grep autoDelete
```

Statefull instances will have this set to **false**, stateless will be **true**.

You can suggest adding this information to ***cloud compute instance-groups describe*** in [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @Sergiusz Thank you for your inputs, it sounds like a workaround, but it serves the purpose. I will try posting a request on the issue tracker.